# Cannot set property '0' of undefined , creating multidimensional array in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to group objects by key 'pokoj'.

```
var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
            {
                array[events[i]['pokoj']][i] = events[i]; 


            }
console.log(array);
```

Comment: `array[events[i]['pokoj']]` is `undefined`. You need to initialize it before accessing it via `[i]`

Comment: Why did someone voted to close this as "question on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration"?

Comment: I vote to close aforementioned close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check first if the subarray exists and if not, create it:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  if (!(events[i]['pokoj'] in array)) {
    array[events[i]['pokoj']] = [];
  }
  array[events[i]['pokoj']][i] = events[i]; 
}
console.log(array);
```